# Using TP-Link Archer VR400 as Access Point with a shared USB storage

Tags: router, wireless-access-point, usb-storage

I bought and set up a Archer VR400 as an access point (Connected LAN to LAN with the main modem-router, DHCP was disabled).
Everything looked like it is working. 
The VR400 served one Lan client and few wireless ones.

I also connected the router a USB external storage. It was recognized by the outer as it was displayed in the management interface. 
However, the hard drive was not accessible by the other VR400 clients. They didn't even see it.

I wounder why whether it is one the following reasons:

1. I **did not** changed the VR 400 IP address, and it was outside the main router subnet
2. DCPH is disabled, which is must.
3. This device according the TP-Link support does not support Access Point mode. They refuse to say what is the problem if any, and wont discuss anything else. They only recommend the C7 router, that have an operation mode "Access Point", without needing any manual setting (like disabling DHCP).

For now, I have returned the router, but still considering buying it again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, internet access was fine however it couldn't see anything on my LAN, no network shares etc. I has plugged into the LAN4/WAN port originally, try using one of the other LAN ports instead - it worked for me. Weirdly, I don't seem to be able to log into the ARCHER VR400 now though.. like its vanished!

Comment: I was having the same problem. Set the IP address to 192.168.1.2 and disabled DHCP. Plugged it into the LAN4/WAN port as advised for other tp-link router/access points. No luck. Then I changed the port away from LAN4/WAN and it worked straight away. Thanks!

Comment: The VR400 doesn't appear on the list of connected devices on the new router, but I can access its control panel at the IP address 192.168.1.2 that I manually set it to before.